# Nullspace of a linear mapping from higher to lower dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, algebraic-geometry

It is a well-known fact that a linear mapping $A: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ , where $m < n$, has a non-trivial null space. This follows from the "rank-nullity" theorem of linear algebra.

This result somewhat seems to intuitively true - something that "flattens" out the the space should send some elements to zero.

My first question is can this fact be proved (using analytical methods, for example) without introducing the notion of a basis and its dimension?

More generally, can this result be extended to "appropriate" non-linear mappings $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$, where $m < n$ (of course, the term "null-space" would not make sense; we just ask for the existence of non-trivial zeros)?

Comment: It should be noted that the usual analysis differentiable non-linear mappings relies heavily on the fact that a differentiable function is "basically linear" in a small neighborhood of any point, then applies the properties of linear maps.

Answer (score 1):

1. Sure. You write a matrix $M$ for the transformation (which arguably uses the notion of basis**, but...) and do row reduction to produce a matrix $M'$. Row-reduction doesn't change the kernel. But in the row-reduced matrix, pick column that does not contain the leading "1" in a row, say column $i$. (There has to be such a column because $m < n$). Then it's easy to construct a vector $v$ with a "1" in slot $i$ and perhaps some nonzero entries in other slots such that $M' v = 0$, showing the kernel's nontrivial. (The nonzero entries in $v$ are the negatives of the entries in column $i$ of $M'$, placed in the slots corresponding to columns of $M'$ that contain a leading $1$.)

   ** Well...not really. The columns of the matrix $M$ are just $T(e_i)$, where the $e_i$ are the vectors that are all 0 except for a 1 in slot $i$.
2. For differentiable mappings, the inverse/implicit function theorems capture the behavior you're talking about, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question, there are certainly theorems ruling out the existence of such $f$ assuming $f$ is continuous or smooth or algebraic or whatever. (I'm thinking of proofs using (co)homological methods.) But I would expect that these proofs ultimately make use of linear mappings as a base case somewhere (especially when $f$ is assumed differentiable -- we then consider (linear) maps of tangent spaces).

Regarding your last question, rather than 'kernel' or 'nullspace' (set of elements $x$ such that $f(x) = 0$), one can consider, for general functions $f : X \to Y$, the fiber product

$$X \times_f X = \{(x_1,x_2) : f(x_1) = f(x_2)\} \subset X \times X.$$

If $f$ is injective, $X \times_f X \cong \Delta(X) \cong X$. Otherwise the fibers of $X \times_f X$ over $Y$ (by specifying $f(\_) = y$) describe the noninjectivity of $f$ piece-by-piece.

Anyway, the point is that you can still ask about (non-)injectivity, if your function is nonlinear. Of course, it's a theorem of topology that there is no continuous injection $f: \mathbb{R}^n \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ with $n > m$, so $\mathbb{R}^n \times_f \mathbb{R}^n$ will have interesting fibers.